# MVC disable cache for controller action in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have controller action decorated with OutputCache attribute:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 60 * 12, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult GetProducts(int id, string template, string version)
```

I would like to disable it in debug mode so I have used web.config transformation so in DEBUG mode I get this extra lines:

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" enableFragmentCache="false" />
</caching>
```

But cache still works - action result is cached, changing code inside view make no effect when rendered.

Any ideas?

IT Man

Comment: Wrap your `[OutputCache]` attribute in `#if !DEBUG` statement

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
#if (!DEBUG)
[OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 60 * 12, VaryByParam = "*")]
#endif
```

**[#if (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)**

Comment: Its a bit dirty and decentralized approach, but if there's no other way I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CacheProfile`:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "CacheProfile1")]
public ActionResult GetProducts(int id, string template, string version)
```

web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="CacheProfile1" duration="0" varyByParam="*" />
      </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

Transformation at web.Release.config:

```
<system.web>  
  <caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="CacheProfile1" duration="43200" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

When publishing it a release mode it will produce this for web.config:

```
<add name="CacheProfile1" duration="43200" varyByParam="*" />
```